# error when import Eof module (udunits error, os error)

Tags: python

```
from eofs.standard import Eof
```

i got the error when i import Eof. 
This is the error:

```
UdunitsError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cf_units\__init__.py in <module>
    188     try:
--> 189         _ud_system = _ud.read_xml()
    190     except _ud.UdunitsError:

cf_units/_udunits2.pyx in cf_units._udunits2.read_xml()


cf_units/_udunits2.pyx in cf_units._udunits2.wrap_system()

cf_units/_udunits2.pyx in cf_units._udunits2._raise_error()

UdunitsError: UT_OPEN_DEFAULT: b'No such file or directory'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

UdunitsError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cf_units\__init__.py in <module>
    195         try:
--> 196             _ud_system = _ud.read_xml(_alt_xml_path.encode())
    197         except _ud.UdunitsError as e:

cf_units/_udunits2.pyx in cf_units._udunits2.read_xml()

cf_units/_udunits2.pyx in cf_units._udunits2.wrap_system()

cf_units/_udunits2.pyx in cf_units._udunits2._raise_error()

UdunitsError: UT_OPEN_ARG: b'No such file or directory'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-59a1f1d00c07> in <module>
     14 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
     15 from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
---> 16 from eofs.standard import Eof

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\eofs\__init__.py in <module>
     19 
     20 from . import standard
---> 21 from . import tools
     22 
     23 from ._version import get_versions

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\eofs\tools\__init__.py in <module>
     32 
     33 try:
---> 34     from . import iris
     35     __all__.append('iris')
     36 except ImportError:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\eofs\tools\iris.py in <module>
     22 
     23 import numpy as np
---> 24 from iris.cube import Cube
     25 from iris.analysis.cartography import area_weights
     26 from iris.analysis.cartography import cosine_latitude_weights

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\iris\__init__.py in <module>
    108 
    109 import iris.config
--> 110 import iris.cube
    111 import iris._constraints
    112 from iris._deprecation import IrisDeprecation, warn_deprecated

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\iris\cube.py in <module>
     51 import numpy.ma as ma
     52 
---> 53 from iris._cube_coord_common import CFVariableMixin
     54 import iris._concatenate
     55 import iris._constraints

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\iris\_cube_coord_common.py in <module>
     25 import string
     26 
---> 27 import cf_units
     28 
     29 import iris.std_names

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cf_units\__init__.py in <module>
    199             raise OSError(
    200                 '[%s] Failed to open UDUNITS-2 XML unit database%s'
--> 201                 % (e.status_msg(), error_msg))
    202 
    203 

OSError: [UT_OPEN_ARG] Failed to open UDUNITS-2 XML unit database: "b'No such file or directory'"
```

could you help me,please?

Answer (score 1):

I have met the same problem and I just fixed it!

1. Find where your Anaconda3 files are located (path on my computer is C:\Users\asus\Anaconda3).
2. Find and open the folder named "Library", find and open the folder "share" inside the "Library" (path on my computer is C:\Users\asus\Anaconda3\Library\share).
3. Inside "share", you have the folder "udunits2" if you have completed the installation of all requirements packages (path in my computer is C:\Users\asus\Anaconda3\Library\share\udunits).

   Copy the folder "udunits2".
4. Go back to C:\Users\asus\Anaconda3.

   **Important:** Find the folder "share" in the current directory (path on my computer is C:\Users\asus\Anaconda3\share).
5. Paste the "udunits2" into this "share" folder.

Explanation:

So there are two "share" folders in Anaconda. When you import eofs, the cf_units package is using the path C:\Users\asus\Anaconda3\share

However, the file "UDUNITS-2 XML" locates in C:\Users\asus\Anaconda3\Library\share\udunits

You may open the  *init*.py to have a look.

[image]

After I copy the "udunits" folder to C:\Users\asus\Anaconda3\share, files are able to be found.

Try to import eofs again!

Comment: Hi Shijing, and welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited your post to fix some minor formatting issues. You can find some help on how to format posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Also, I've removed your email address from your post. On Stack Overflow, we strongly discourage contacting users off-site. We prefer to keep all discussion here, so others can find it. If people have questions, they can leave comments (like this one) under your answer.